# Linking and counting records with one or multiple criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count, group-by

I am attempting to link together some records to identify sibling groups.  The way we can do this is to identify clients who share the same parents.

A sample of the SQL follows:

```
SELECT
A.ClientID,
B.ParentID

FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.ClientID to A.ClientID
AND B.REL_END is NULL AND B.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
```

Which would return data in the following format:

```
     Client ID     Parent ID
     1             A
     1             B
     2             C
     2             D
     3             C
     3             E
     4             C
     4             D
```

How I would like it to appear follows:

```
     Client ID    No. of Siblings
     1            0
     2            2
     3            2
     4            2
```

Hopefully the table shows that child 1 has 0 siblings (shares no parents with 2,3,4), child 2 has 2 siblings (3 and 4), child 3 has 2 siblings (2 and 4) and child 4 has 2 siblings (2,3).  It seems like it should be simple enough to achieve this but I'm really struggling at the minute to think how!  I think it's made slightly more confusing because a child may share only one parent with another child to be considered as a sibling.

Hopefully this is clear, thanks.

Edit: Just to make it clear, the relationship is identified by a child sharing a parent ID with another child (the ids are unique, but I provided generic ones for this example).  So as Child 2, 3 and 4 all have a parent with an id of C they are considered siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  If you can assume exactly two parents for each child, then you can do something like:

```
select c.*, count(*) over (partition by min_parent, max_parent) - 1 as NumSiblings
from (SELECT A.ClientID, min(B.ParentID) as min_parent, max(b.parentid) as max_parent
      FROM A LEFT JOIN
           B
           ON B.ClientID to A.ClientID AND B.REL_END is NULL AND B.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
      group by a.clientid
     ) c
```

What this does is calculate the two parents for each client.  It then uses the windows function to count the number of clients that have exactly the same parents.  The "-1" is because all children are counted, and we don't want to count the current child.

If you can have more than two parents, then the query is more complicated.

If you want only one parent being shared (rather than two), then you can handle using a self join:

```
with cp as (SELECT A.ClientID, B.ParentID
            FROM A LEFT JOIN
                 B
                 ON B.ClientID to A.ClientID AND B.REL_END is NULL AND B.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
           )
select cp.client_id, count(distinct cp1.client_id) as NumSiblings
from cp left outer join
     cp cp1
     on cp.parent_id = cp1.parent_id and cp.client_id <> cp1.client_id
group by cp.client_id
```

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff:  Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately, I was also interested in picking up cases were a child shared a parent, but didn't necessarily have the exact same parents (so child 1 might have parent a and b, and child 2 might have parent a and c - these should be considered as siblings as they share parent A) - I've run this and it certainly does pick up those with the same parents but not those who share just one parent.  Still, at least I can be comforted in knowing it wasn't as simple as I thought it might have been!

Comment: Thanks, the second query appears to be working very well!  Your assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You may try this query, it displays to me the desired output.

```
with c_data as (
    select a.clientid, b.parentid, count(a.clientid) over (partition by parentid order by     parentid) as c_parents
    FROM A
      LEFT JOIN B ON (B.ClientID = A.ClientID)
        AND B.REL_END is NULL AND B.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
)
select clientid as "Client ID", max(c_parents) -1 as "No of Siblings"
from c_data
group by clientid;
```

Example:

```
SQL> with c_data as (
  2  select a.clientid, b.parentid, count(a.clientid) over (partition by parentid order by parentid) as c_parents
  3  FROM A
  4  LEFT JOIN B ON (B.ClientID = A.ClientID)
  5  AND B.REL_END is NULL AND B.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
  6  )
  7  select clientid as "Client ID", max(c_parents) -1 as "No of Siblings"
  8  from c_data
  9  group by clientid;

 Client ID No of Siblings
---------- --------------
         1              0
         2              2
         4              2
         3              2

Transcurrido: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
```

With the analytic function we count all client id's partitioned by the parentid related of the current tupple to count all clients that have in common the same parent.

After in the projection, we get the max number of parent in common for each client and substracts 1, the client itself.

Hope this helps!

Regards!

Comment: By the way, I tested this solution on a 11gR2 Database

Comment: Thanks for your response - this does look promising based on what you've said, when I run the query though it's giving me some very odd numbers (clients with 102 siblings!) which I know isn't right.  It could be something to do with Table B, which actually holds all relationships for a client - though the REL_CODE and REL_END should ensure only 'parent relationships' count.

Comment: Could you please attach a test case?

Comment: sorry, what is the best way to attach a test case?  I wonder if there's a problem with my end - I will check some things and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: I'm new here, but I sugget to use pastebin (http://pastebin.com/) to attach a sample dataset or the complete table structure; I was thinking on your problem and I believe is not that hard, but I'm missing something maybe because the example has a very tiny dataset.

Comment: @IronDrake, I would suggest [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for test cases. It means that anyone can fork what you've done (automatically) and test stuff for themselves.

Comment: By altering the query slightly (adding a distinct to the select and count within the 'with c_data' part), I can get this to produce very similar results to the query posted by @Gordon Linoff.  Thanks very much for your assistance, though I'll be marking Gordon's as the answer as it works without adjustment (though as you say my simplified dataset wouldn't show all the complications of the actual tables.)  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't understand how the table and relation are made, but you could do something like that :

```
SELECT ClientID, sum(NumberOfSibling) as NumberOfSibling
from(
    SELECT A.ClientID, (select count(ClientID) 
                        from A2
                        LEFT JOIN B2 ON B2.ClientID to A2.ClientID
                        AND B2.REL_END is NULL AND B2.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
                        where B2.ParentID = B.ParentID) as NumberOfSibling
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.ClientID to A.ClientID
    AND B.REL_END is NULL AND B.REL_CODE = 'PAR'
) GROUP BY ClientID
```

Explanation : I took your request and modify the second result to return the sum of siblings wich possess  the same Parent (that's `the select count(*) ...`, that's also the part I'm not sure about the conditions). And put this in another to group by ClientID to have the sum of the 2 parents.

Comment: thanks for responding, though I'm not sure I understand this - wouldn't B2 have to be declared somewhere for this to work? Also should LEFT JOIN B ON B2.ClientID to A2.ClientID  be LEFT JOIN B ON B2.ClientID = A2.ClientID as I'm getting an invalid relational operator error when using 'to'.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, unfortunately in this case I couldn't get this query to work though I suspect this was due to my own ineptitude than anything else.